# Example of code after clicking button (AJAX W3Schools example)

Tags: ajax

I was wondering if anyone could give me an example of what the code looks like after you click the button in this W3Schools example:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_xml2

What does the table code look like afterwards?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome or Firefox, you can right-click on the table and select "Inspect Element". That will enable you to see the frame source.

As for that specific example, it's just a plain-vanilla table in a very simple HTML document.